# Benefits of type-safe library (Morphia)

Tags: morphia, type-safety

I'm thinking to use Morphia with my GWT mongoDB project but I'm wondering
what are the benefits of type-safe library like Morphia?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's type-safe. No, kidding aside, the Morphia API is much nicer to interact with.

To save an entity with the plain Java driver you'd do something like this:

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("name", "xeraa");
document.put("age", 30);
document.put("createdDate", new Date());
table.insert(document);
```

So you are basically putting together plain DBObjects - for inserting, updating, and querying like this:

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("age", "30");
DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);
```

In Morphia you annotate your entities in a JPA like fashion:

```
@Entity
class FooEntity {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Date date = new Date();
}
```

So you create your objects and simply persist them. Also the fluent query interface is much nicer where you can do things like `ds.createQuery(FooEntity.class).field("age").equal(30).asList();`